# $\frac{\sqrt{9+x}{-3}}{x}$ for $x = 10^{-n}$, $n \in \{4,...,13\}$ and interpret the observations

Tags: numerical-methods, python

I am looking for some help with the following question. I am really stuck!

I am trying to use python to evaluate

$$\frac{\sqrt{9+x}{-3}}{x}$$

for $x = 10^{-n}$, $n \in \{4,...,13\}$ and interpret the observations. Is there a better way to evaluate this expression?

I am not sure how to proceed with this, maybe multiplying by a conjugate and evaluating would be better?

Comment: As you say, "maybe multiplying by a conjugate and evaluating would be better".

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown would that be a better way to evaluate the expression? why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously if you multiply the numerator and denominator by the conjugate expression$\sqrt{9+x}+3$, you can prove that the limiting value is $1/6$.  To wit:

$\frac{\sqrt{9+x}-3}{x}=\frac{9+x-3^2}{x(\sqrt{9+x}+3)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{9+x}+3}\rightarrow 1/6 \text{ as }x\rightarrow 0$

But I suspect this is a computer exercise, meaning you should just punch the expression into your computer or calculator and see what happens.

If your machine is like most machines (all machines if you keep trying lower powers of ten), you seem to approach $0.16666...$ with no problem ... until, when the absolute value of the exponent gets large enough, there are suddenly random deviations that keep getting worse.  That is what you should be looking for, and interpreting as **ill conditioning when you subtract numbers close to each other.**

If you put in the conjugate factor in the numerator and denominator and try again, you kill the deviations.  This is an example of **removing the ill-conditioned operation.**

Comment: this is an excellent explanation! What did you use to get this information? pyton?

Comment: I did exercises like this in my computer programming classes.  Fortran IV, Pascal, C, Python, it does not matter and (at least in the long run) neither does the machine.  It's universal in the world of computers/calculators.

Comment: i dont understand your edit, isnt the conjugate $\sqrt{9+x}+3$. Doesnt that give a different answer when multiplied?

Comment: Random deviations in the computed result.  The computer can't give the square root exactly because that needs infinitely many decimal places, and that leads you down the garden path.

Comment: Mistyped a sign.

Comment: okay now it makes sense thanks! last question, why take x as it approaches 0?